# Apache storm can't access UI

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have apache-storm-1.1.0,
try to get storm UI on localhost:8080 and have this:

org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:111)

Also can't kill storm topology from comand line,have the same error message
Please help me, my storm.yaml:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "localhost"
storm.local.dir: "/home/igor/Downloads/apache-storm-1.1.0/bin/data"
nimbus.host: "localhost"
supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6700
 - 6701
 - 6702
 - 6703
nimbus.seeds : ["localhost"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your nimbus server isn't running. Take a look at [how to setup a storm cluster](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.0/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html).

From your master machine run the following to start nimbus:

```
bin/storm nimbus
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when a leader election takes place in the nimbus and the nimbus host fails the election as it does not have the appropriate JARs of your running topology in its local directory.

The only fix I was able to find for this was to either remove the storm related data from zookeeper or reinstall the zookeeper altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but how can I do it? Because in storm 1.1 zookeeper is embedded.

Comment: You could try reinstalling storm, if the number of nodes you are using is less. Or, use the Zookeeper client to delete the data related to storm.

Answer (score 0):

better you go through this link

[https://vincenzogulisano.com/2015/07/30/5-minutes-storm-installation-guide-single-node-setup/][1]

Answer (score 0):

i think you should remove

```
nimbus.seeds : ["localhost"]
```

because in earlier version of storm `nimbus.host` was been used but in version 1 on-wards it been changes to `nimbus.seeds`.

for me `nimbus.host` worked well.

so use either of them. i will suggest to go with `nimbus.host` because it worked well for me.

below is my configuration for `storm.yaml`.

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "localhost"
storm.local.dir: "xxx/data"
nimbus.host: "localhost"
supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6700
 - 6701
 - 6702
 - 6703
```